# Права пользователей на public Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm, permissions, realm-database

Задача: раздать всем пользователям права на запись (.write) на public Realm
Авторизация проходит успешно, авторизуюсь под админом. Но на этапе

```
currentUser.apply(permission, callback: { (error) in
                                if let error = error {
                                    print("Error when attempting to set permissions: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                } else {
                                    print("Permissions successfully set")
                                }
                            })
```

в программе ничего не происходит, ни положительного завершения, ни отрицательного. В логах ROS в этот момент проскакивает след строка:
info: [http] 127.0.0.1 - POST /auth HTTP/1.1 400 465 - 0.640 ms
Весь код авторизации и применения прав доступа

```
SyncUser.logIn(with: usernameCredentials, server: syncServerURL) { (user, error) in
            if error == nil {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    guard let currentUser = user else {return}
                    let config: Realm.Configuration = commonRealmConfig(user: currentUser)
                    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config

                    print("Success login", currentUser)

                    Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: config, callback: { (realm, error) in
                        if let realm = realm {
                            print("Open REALM async")
                            if currentUser.isAdmin {
                                print("ADMIN user")
                                let permission = SyncPermission(realmPath: realm.configuration.syncConfiguration!.realmURL.path, identity: "*", accessLevel: .write)

                                currentUser.apply(permission, callback: { (error) in
                                    if let error = error {
                                        print("Error when attempting to set permissions: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                    } else {
                                        print("Permissions successfully set")
                                    }
                                })
                                //for test
                                currentUser.retrieveInfo(forUser: "Alex", identityProvider: .usernamePassword, completion: { (info, error) in
                                    if let info = info {
                                        print("Info: ", info.identity)
                                    } else {
                                        print("Err info")
                                    }
                                })
                            }

                        } else if let error = error {
                            print("Error asyncOpen: ", error.localizedDescription)
                        }
                    })


                        completion(true, user)


                }


            } else {
                print("Error: ", error!.localizedDescription)
                completion(false, nil)
            }
        }
```

А вот кусок кода

```
currentUser.retrieveInfo(forUser: "Alex", identityProvider: .usernamePassword, completion: { (info, error) in
                                if let info = info {
                                    print("Info: ", info.identity)
                                } else {
                                    print("Err info")
                                }
                            })
```

Выполняется нормально, прилетают данные

Подскажите, в чём может быть дело/ Может быть кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой